# Flutter Future builder, future gets called multiple times

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**Problem:** I have a future builder inside a **Column** which is inside a **SingleChildScrollView**
It calls its future multiple times(Infinite).

---

```
 FutureBuilder(
                    future: ProductLoaderUtil.getSimilarProducts(
                        context, widget.productItem.productCategoryId),
                    builder: (context, val) {
                      if (val.hasData && (!val.hasError))
                        return ListProductHorizontal(
                          productItemsHorizontal: val.data,
                          flag: false,
                        );
                      else
                        return Container(
                          height: _height * 0.06,
                          color: FakeWhite,
                        );
                    },
                  ),
```

---

The function getting called is this,

```
         static Future<List<ProductItem>> getSimilarProducts(
                BuildContext context, String category) async {
                List<ProductItem> products = [];
                String categoryName = categories[0];
  
                debugPrint(categoryName + " --- ");
                await Firestore.instance
                    .collection("GlobalDataBase")
                    .document(categoryName)
                    .collection("ITEMS")
                    .limit(4)
                    .getDocuments()
                    .then((value) {
                  value.documents.forEach((element) {
            //        debugPrint(element.data.toString());
                    products.add(ProductItem.fromJson(element.data));
                  });
                });
                return products;
              }
```

Comment: Are you using multiple `FutureBuilders` or any older builders above the given widget? In your code you call `getPopularProducts`, but you give the implementation of `getSimilarProducts`, can you show the implementation of `getPopularProducts` as well?

Comment: Ahh! that's exactly the same, just the name, edited.

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen I have a Future builder separate from this i.e it's a column member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's probably because somewhere you use `setState()` and when you that your widget tree get re-build and the `FutureBuilder` call the `future` method again, to prevent this gain access to the future method in `initState()` by having a stateful widget like this

```dart
// inside state class...
  
   Future getPopluarProductsFuture;

   @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getPopularProductsFuture = getPopularProducts(
                        context, widget.productItem.productCategoryId);
  }

 // now for the FutureBuilder make it like this 
  FutureBuilder(
   future: getPopularProductsFuture,
   builder: ......
)
```